# ForEach - display results from API

Tags: javascript, api, foreach, mapping, array.prototype.map

Having trouble, trying to access the 'title' value, in this array of objects.

It's a giphy api and you can see below, I'm using `fetch` to call the api.  And the loop through the data using `forEach`.

I can call the api and console log an array, containing 5 objects. However, I don't think I'm mapping through my data correctly.

For example, when I console.log `console.log('foreach', elem);`, I am return the following in console:

```
foreach 0
foreach 1
foreach 2
foreach 3
foreach 4
```

However, when I `console.log('foreach', elem.title);`, I am returned `undefined`. I basically can't access any data in the object, as I am returned undefined all the time.

Here's my code:

```
 fetch('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=ryan+gosling&api_key=MY_API_KEY&limit=5')
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();

    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data.data);    
      // This returns a full array object of data

      let result = '<h2> Random User Info From Jsonplaceholder API</h2>';

      Object.keys(data.data).forEach(elem => {
        console.log('foreach', elem);


        result +=
                `<div>
                 <h5> User ID: ${elem} </h5>

                  </div>`;
        place.innerHTML = result;
      });
    });
```

Basically, I think I'm doing something wrong in my ForEach.

Comment: You're looping on keys. `data.data[elem].title` should be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that your `data` is array of objects. If you will use `Object.key()` on `array`. It will return indexes of `array` i.e `0,1,2,3...`. You need to call `forEach()` directly on array

```
data.data.forEach(elem => {
        console.log('foreach', elem);
});
```

To access the property of the item use [Dot Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation)

```
data.data.forEach(elem => {
       console.log('foreach', elem.title);
});
```

Comment: Aaaaah, amazing, thank you! I did try this about 3 hours ago, but that was before I realised I needed to call data.data.  (And not just data).  Thank you!

Comment: @Reena Verma Accept the answer if it helped